# Check if input field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check live if an input field is empty.

I have the following working function:

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2KnqX/)

I tried it with this

```
if( $("input").val().length == 0 ) { ... }
```

but it doesn't work.

The function shouldn't output the alert if the input is empty.

Here is the code, but it doesn't work:

```
    var timer;

$("input").bind("keyup", function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(changeFn, 1000)
});


if( $("input").val().length != 0 ) {
    function changeFn(){
        alert('Changed');
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have that check in your fiddle. Your fiddle will always alert. What did you expect?

Comment: what you actully want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works just fine, see this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bk4Zv/

```
function changeFn(){
    alert('Changed');

    if( $("input").val().length == 0 ) { 
        alert("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: But the alert "Changed" is also displayed when the input is empty ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bk4Zv/1/ again check your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

this should work :

```
if( $("input").val() == "" ) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function changeFn(){


    if( $("input").val().length == 0 ) { 
        alert("Empty");
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Changed');
    }    
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk4Zv/1/)